# Building Rails 3 Engine Throwing Gem::Package::TooLongFileName Error

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-engines

I'm trying to build my engine using `gem build myengine` but I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Package::TooLongFileName)
    Gem::Package::TooLongFileName
```

I wouldn't expect `myengine` not to be too long of a name. Any idea what might be going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this issue by finding the exact file that was causing the issue - it was a migration file with a long name.

For those who are interested, the error is thrown from the `split_name` method of `TarWriter` class of the `rubygems` source code. This error will bet thrown if:

1. The relative path of a file, include the file name itself, is greater than 256 characters
2. The file name is greater than 100 characters
3. The file prefix is greater than 155 characters

I hope this helps. I've attached the source code for the `split_name` method below for review.

```
def split_name(name) # :nodoc:
  raise Gem::Package::TooLongFileName if name.size > 256

  if name.size <= 100 then
    prefix = ""
  else
    parts = name.split(/\//)
    newname = parts.pop
    nxt = ""

    loop do
      nxt = parts.pop
      break if newname.size + 1 + nxt.size > 100
      newname = nxt + "/" + newname
    end

    prefix = (parts + [nxt]).join "/"
    name = newname

    if name.size > 100 or prefix.size > 155 then
      raise Gem::Package::TooLongFileName
    end
  end

  return name, prefix
end
```

Comment: Wow. This is indeed retarded. I have just filed an issue to rubygem-github to get rid of this arbitrary limitation. Whoever wrote it and pushed it into rubygems must have been a clueless random noob. I actually googled for that error and found github issues where people ran into the same problem. Apparently the guy who wrote it thinks that 155 is a holy number. What if he would have set the limit to 42 ...

Answer (score 4):

I solved this Problem by updateing rubygems to 1.8.25 (gem update --system)

-edit-

check your project.gemspec file: 
comment out

```
s.files = ... or s.test_files = ...
```

if there is any file in your project with a name too long

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the issue is still happening for me.

Comment: "I wouldn't expect myengine not to be too long of a name." There could be any file in your Project, which causes this error, not just the project name.

Comment: Commenting out `s.test_files` resolves `Gem::Package::TooLongFileName` from being thrown, but I can't really comment that out. Those files need to be included in the gem.

Comment: indeed, but maybe in your test files is a file name too long (an very long controller spec name)?

Comment: In the test/dummy app there

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by removing the test/dummy/tmp folder and .sass_cache folder, because they contains long file names